# Radgrid Export with currency value

Tags: export-to-excel, radgrid

I'm using radgrid to export to excel file. Everything is ok except one thing. I would like to format the value as currency style but when exporting done the style is Accounting

I catch the event

```
grid_ExcelExportCellFormatting(object source, ExcelExportCellFormattingEventArgs e)
```

and I handled in this as below

```
e.Cell.Style["mso-number-format"] = "Currency";
```

Please help!

---

**[EDITED ON 28 June 2012]**
Following The links as Daniel Benitez provide. I solved this issue.
And I have some experience from it.

Refer [my personal article](http://kimcuhoang.blogspot.com/2012/06/radgrid-export-to-excel-with-custom.html) if you interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's documentation on the Office HTML format is insufficient and vague. You can see it below:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155477%28office.10%29.aspx

(There is a CHM file packed within the self-extracting archive which you may prefer to unpack manually)

If this is not working for your scenario, you may use a custom number format that mimics the default Currency format. Some examples are available below:

http://niallodoherty.com/post.cfm/basic-html-to-excel-formatting

http://agoric.com/sources/software/htmltoExcel

http://cosicimiento.blogspot.com/2008/11/styling-excel-cells-with-mso-number.html

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-html-export.html

Another thing you could try is a bit of reverse-engineering-like approach. Namely:

- export the file and then open it in Excel
- set Currency format to the top left cell in the sheet
- save the file as HTML
- open it in Notepad++ or alternative text editor and examine how MS Excel set this :)

I hope this helps :)